# Matlab implementation of neural network is vastly superior to Keras variant

Tags: matlab, neural-network, keras, curve-fitting

In order to compare both variants, I tried to implement an easy example: learning the sinc-function.

Matlab is pretty straightforward here, creating the data with

```
x = 0 : 0.1 : 10;
y = sin(x) ./ x;
```

and training with the Neural Network Fitting fitting tool.
Matlab yielded a loss of 5.31e-10 after just 62 epochs.

[image]

As you can see, a perfect fit to the naked eye.
Now I implemented the same network with keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('linear'))

opti = Adam()

model.compile(optimizer=opti,
              loss='mean_squared_error')
```

and prepared the data in a similar way:

```
x = np.arange(0, 10.1, 0.1)

def sinc(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return (np.sin(x) / x)

y = [sinc(val) for val in x]
```

and training with

```
history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=100, validation_split=0.15)
```

After 100 epochs, the loss was at roughly 0.02.

[image]

Keras' performance is obviously much worse than Matlabs.

The only thing I could think of was that Levenberg-Marquardt is ridiculously superior to Adam, because training loss didn't improve much, even after 1000 epochs.

I also tried increasing the learning rate of Adam, but even then loss just stopped decreasing at around 0.0003

Here is a link to a Jupyter notebook, if you want to take a look at the exact code I'm using for my Keras implementation:

[Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/Tabascl/keras-vs-matlab/blob/master/vsmatlab.ipynb)

Now my question is if and how I can improve on my Keras implementation without leaving the obvious constraints (like increasing the hidden layer size) imposed by my challenge to beat Matlab too much?

Comment: Yes LM is better than adam and can lead to such results.

Comment: LM is better in this case. But often the higher performance on toy problems doesn't extend to more complex problems.

Comment: And what is your question? :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments!

@Cleb My question is if and how I can improve the Keras implementation, forgot that

Comment: You should send a box of chocolate to the NN team in Mathworks, I guess

Comment: @refl3x consider adding that question to your post so users know how to help you

Comment: @DarkCygnus Done!

Comment: @refl3x good :) added an answer that may help you here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now my question is if and how I can improve on my Keras implementation without leaving the obvious constraints (like increasing the hidden layer size) imposed by my challenge to beat Matlab too much?

To improve your Keras implementation I suggest you first **play around a bit with other optimizers available** by default, as one of them may be ideal for your situation and perhaps surpass Matlab's implementation.

If that doesn't work you can still **create a custom optimizer class**, that fits your needs. In your case you could try implementing the Levenberg-Marquardt optimizer on your own. For that you should extend the `Optimizers` class and override the `get_updates` and `get_config` methods, something like:

```
class myLM(Optimizer):
    def __init__(self, your=0., parameters=0., here=0., **kwargs):
       #Initialize your custom Optimizer
    def get_updates(self, loss, params):
       #Calculate and return the update according to LM implementation
       return self.updates
    def get_config(self):
       #override configuration method
       config = {'your': float(K.get_value(self.lr)),
              'parameters': float(K.get_value(self.beta_1)),
              'here': float(K.get_value(self.beta_2)),
               }
       base_config = super(myML, self).get_config() #other configs
       return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

You can then instantiate your custom optimizer and pass it to `optimizer` when compiling your model.

I suggest you check the [Keras Optimizers](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L397) code (in this case for example, Adam), so you can know what each method is expected to return and be able to build them up to your custom needs.